# Как получить сумму товаров в корзине из БД?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, mysqli

Друзья всем привет сразу скажу что я шкила ну и тип учу PHP!

К проблеме:
Я делаю интернет магазин с нуля на PHP и сейчас начал делать корзину, а в корзинах как извесно есть общая сума всех товаров, ну тип все что мы помучили с базы данных нужно додать и вывести echo ;

```
<?php

$msq = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM store_basket WHERE user_id = '$my_id'");
?>
```

И так я вывожу все с таблицы store_basket где юзер id ровно моему, и в талице к каждому товару есть пункт 'price' тип цена товара и мне нужно цены из всех товаров подобавлять в одну переменую ну и потом тип вывести!

Я остановился на этом:

МОЙ ГОВНОКОД, НЕ РАБОЧИЙ!!! -

```
<h5>Всего: <?php $msq = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM store_basket WHERE user_id = '$my_id'");

while ($dff = mysqli_fetch_assoc($msq)) {
$rpm = $dff['price'];
}

for ($i=0; $i < 1; $i++) {
$d = $d + $dff;
}
echo $d;



?> грн</h5>
```

Comment: вместо всего кода `echo array_sum(array_column(mysqli_fetch_all($msq, MYSQLI_ASSOC),'price'));`

Comment: Огромное спасибо, 2 дня мучился!

Comment: Оформите это в ответе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первую очередь здесь надо учить SQL. Потому что данная задача решается прямо в запросе.

Плюс надо не забывать, что кроме стоимости товара в корзине так же указывается и *количество*. Поэтому пишем запрос, сначала в чистом SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(price*quantity) FROM store_basket WHERE user_id = 1;
```

Если все верно, то переписываем запрос на РНР:

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(price*quantity) FROM store_basket WHERE user_id = ?";
$stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $my_id);
$stmt->exeute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_row();
$sum = $row[0];
```